# Issues with Image Upload and Form Validation in Next.js 14 with Shadcn, Zod, and React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, zod

I'm currently working on a Next.js 14 application using Shadcn, Zod, and React Hook Form, and I'm facing several issues with image upload and form validation. I have a form for creating a user profile, and I'm using the createProfile function to submit the form data, including an image. However, I'm encountering the following problems:

- Image Upload Issue - The Django backend responds with the error message: "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.".
- User Id Issue - When submitting the form, Django backend reports an error related to the "user" field: "Invalid pk "0" - object does not exist." I suspect this is related to sending a string instead of a number to the Django backend.
- Commented Field Input Issue - I've commented out an alternative way of handling the image input field in my code. When I use the {...field} approach on that field, my entire application crashes when uploading images. I'm not sure why this happens and would appreciate insights into this issue.
  Here is my code(sorry if it is too large, thought it is better to show the whole thing)
  ProfileForm.tsx

```js
"use client";

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";

import { useGlobalContext } from "@/components/context/GlobalContext";

import { toast } from "@/lib/use-toast";
import { createProfile } from "@/lib/users/createProfile";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";

// https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/387
// https://github.com/blitz-js/blitz/discussions/2292#discussioncomment-826778

const profileFormSchema = z.object({
  full_name: z.string().min(2).max(20),
  address: z.string().min(2).max(50),
  phone_number: z.string().min(2).max(20),
  picture: z
    .any()
    .refine((file) => file?.length == 1, "File is required.")
    .refine(
      (file) =>
        file[0]?.type === "image/png" ||
        file[0]?.type === "image/jpeg" ||
        file[0]?.type === "image/jpg",
      "Must be a png, jpeg or jpg.",
    )
    .refine((file) => file[0]?.size <= 5000000, `Max file size is 5MB.`),
  // picture: typeof window === "undefined" ? z.any() : z.instanceof(File),
});

export type ProfileFormSchemaType = z.infer<typeof profileFormSchema>;

export default function ProfileForm() {
  const { userInfo, setUserInfo, accessToken } = useGlobalContext();

  const form = useForm<ProfileFormSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(profileFormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      full_name: "",
      address: "",
      phone_number: "",
      picture: undefined,
    },
  });

  async function onSubmit(values: ProfileFormSchemaType) {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("picture", values.picture);
    formData.append("full_name", values.full_name);
    formData.append("address", values.address);
    formData.append("phone_number", values.phone_number);
    formData.append("user", String(userInfo.id));

    console.log(formData);

    try {
      const response = await createProfile(formData, accessToken);
      console.log(response);

      toast({
        title: "success",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        title: "error",
        description: error?.toString(),
      });
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  const fileRef = form.register("picture", { required: true });

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className="space-y-8 rounded-tr-2xl rounded-tl-2xl border p-8"
      >
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="full_name"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Full name</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="John Doe" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="phone_number"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Phone number</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="+38269123123" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="address"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Address</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="Podgorica, Donja Gorica" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        {/* <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="picture"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Picture</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input
                  accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg"
                  type="file"
                  placeholder="profile image"
                  {...fileRef}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        /> */}

        <Label htmlFor="picture">Picture</Label>

        <Input
          id="picture"
          type="file"
          placeholder="profile image"
          {...form.register("picture", { required: true })}
        />
        {form.formState.errors.picture && (
          <div>
            <span>This field is required</span>
          </div>
        )}
        <Button
          disabled={form.formState.isSubmitting}
          type="submit"
          className={"block mx-auto px-8"}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

and the createProfile function being called in onSubmit:
createProfile.ts:

```js
"use server";

import { env } from "@/lib/zod_schemas/envSchema";

type ErrorResponse = {
  errors: ProfileErrorApiResponse;
};

export async function createProfile(
  formData: FormData,
  token: string,
): Promise<ProfileSuccessApiResponse | ErrorResponse> {
  let response: Response;
  try {
    response = await fetch(`${env.API_BASE_URL}/products/profile/`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
      headers: {
        // "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
      },
      cache: "no-cache", // This option disables caching
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error: ", error);
    throw new Error("Network error");
  }

  if (response.ok) {
    const responseData: ProfileSuccessApiResponse = await response.json();
    return responseData;
  } else if (response.status === 400) {
    const responseError: ProfileErrorApiResponse = await response.json();
    return { errors: responseError };
  } else {
    throw new Error("Unexpected error. Please try again later!");
  }
}
```

i get these errors from the django backend when i submit:

```json
{
   "errors":{
      "picture":[
         "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
      ],
      "user":[
         "Invalid pk \"0\" - object does not exist."
      ]
   }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you solve this error? I am getting the same error.